# How can I solve the distributive property of the summation multiplication?

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-writing

Assume we have two binary arrays: $f_1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]$ and $f_2=[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]$
and the cumulative sum $g_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6]$ and $g_2 =[1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6]$.

Given the following properties:

- $\sum_{i=1}^{n} f_1[i] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_2[i]$
- $\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_1[i] > \sum_{i=1}^{n} g_2[i]$
- $g_k = \sum_{i=1}^{j} f_k[i] \qquad\forall k \in \{1,2\}$

**Update:**
*What is the value of **m** which satisfies the following equation:*
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i=1}^n \left[f_1[i]*\frac{n-g_1[i-1]}{m-(i-1)}\right]  = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[f_2[i]*\frac{n-g_2[i-1]}{m-(i-1)}\right] 
\end{align}

where $g_1[0]=g_2[0]=0$, $|f|=n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: ok, let me clarify it a little

Comment: What does the $*$ represent? What did you try ?

Comment: I assume you want to prove this for general $x$? Then maybe give the values of $x$ in your example. If you want to prove it just for your $f_1, \, f_2, \,g_1, \,$ and $g_2$ without varying $x$ you can simple calculate wheter your inequaliy holds.

Comment: The notation is very confused. I don't see what $x$ is for, and when it says for example $f_1(x_i)$ it seems to really mean $[f_1(x)]_i$ because $f_1$ cannot be a function that takes a vector/array as input and also takes a single real number as input.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis , is it clear right now?

Comment: Yes, that's much better!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample:

Let $f_1=[8,-8], \, f_2=[0,0]$ and $g_1=[8,0], \, g_2=[0,0]$.
Then
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left[f_1[i]*\frac{n-g_1[i-1]}{n-(i-2)}\right]=8\cdot \frac{2-0}{3}-8\cdot\frac{2-8}{2}>0$$.

Comment: $f_1$ & $f_2$ are binary arrays